# Code is supposed to include all of user's input but stops after third input

Tags: c#

My code first takes  the "s" or "k" or "c" input from the user to display a price. The user enters a coin value to bring down that price. My code works when the user inputs the "s" and the first coin value, but after that it just closes after a fourth input and I'm not sure why.

I tried ReadKey and Console.ReadLine but im not sure where to go from here

```cs
namespace VendingMachine
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Gives user necessary info to operate vending machine
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to vending machine.");
            Console.WriteLine("We offer you (s)oda, coo(k)ies, and (c)hips");
            Console.WriteLine("Please select the product you want to purchase:");
            string userselection = Console.ReadLine();


            if (userselection == "s")
            {
                //Generates a random number between 0 and 5 using the random class
                Random rn = new Random();
                int randomnumber = rn.Next(1, 5);
                double lottery = randomnumber * 10;
                Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You win a coupon with " + lottery + " cents.");

                //soda price after lottery 
                double sodaprice = 100 - lottery;
                Console.WriteLine("You only need to pay " + sodaprice + " cents");
                Console.WriteLine("Please insert a coin of 5, 10, or 25:");
                string coininput = Console.ReadLine();
                double coin = Convert.ToDouble(coininput);


                while (coin > 0)
                {
                    if (coin == 25)
                    {
                        double sodapricecoins = sodaprice - coin;
                        Console.WriteLine("You still owe " + sodapricecoins + " cents.");
                        Console.WriteLine("Please insert a coin of 5, 10, or 25:");
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (coin == 10)
                    {
                        double sodapricecoins = sodaprice - coin;
                        Console.WriteLine("You still owe " + sodapricecoins + " cents.");
                        Console.WriteLine("Please insert a coin of 5, 10, or 25:");
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (coin == 5)
                    {
                        double sodapricecoins = sodaprice - coin;
                        Console.WriteLine("You still owe " + sodapricecoins + " cents.");
                        Console.WriteLine("Please insert a coin of 5, 10, or 25:");
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
}
}
}
```

The program should be running continuously until it hits 0 or negative, I know I don't have that part yet.

Comment: You have a _break_ inside each if. This will break the while loop immediately

Comment: Yeah I was just messing with stuff and forgot to remove that before posting, even if I get rid of it, it still closes.

Comment: If you remove the _break_ then the loop enters an infinite cycle because you never change the _coin_ variable inside the loop. You need to ask again to your user to input again a coin value and you need also to check if the user has payed everything (so another variable is required to keep track of the remainder due after each loop

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to remove the *break* inside the three if, but if you notice the three if contains the same code. They are not needed at all.

The second point is to have a way to exit the loop. This could be when the user types zero for the coin of if the amount due is equal or below zero.

The third point is to ask the coin value inside the loop, do the math and then decide if you want to continue the loop or stop it.

```
Console.WriteLine("You only need to pay " + sodaprice + " cents");
// To force to start the loop, we ask the value inside the loop
double coin = 1d;

// We should reach zero or less starting from the initial price (minus lottery)  
double amountDue = sodaprice;
while (coin > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please insert a coin of 5, 10, or 25:");
    string coininput = Console.ReadLine();

    // use tryparse when trying to convert user input in numbers.
    // tryparse returns true if the input is a number without raising exceptions
    if(double.TryParse(coininput, out coin))
    {

       // Decrement the amount to pay with the user input
       amountDue -= coin;

       // Decide for a message and continue the loop or stop 
        if(amountDue > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("You still owe " + amountDue + " cents.");
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that program runs continuously until sodaprice hits 0 or negative try this code, but your while loop with coin > 0 condition, continue until user types zero or negetive number.

```
//Gives user necessary info to operate vending machine
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to vending machine.");
        Console.WriteLine("We offer you (s)oda, coo(k)ies, and (c)hips");
        Console.WriteLine("Please select the product you want to purchase:");
        string userselection = Console.ReadLine();


        if (userselection == "s")
        {
            //Generates a random number between 0 and 5 using the random class
            double lottery = new Random().Next(1, 5) * 10;
            Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You win a coupon with " + lottery + " cents.");

            //soda price after lottery 
            double sodaprice = 100 - lottery;
            Console.WriteLine("You only need to pay " + sodaprice + " cents");

            double coin;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please insert a coin of 5, 10, or 25:");
                if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out coin))
                {
                    if (coin == 25 || coin == 10 || coin == 5)
                    {
                        sodaprice -= coin;
                        Console.WriteLine(sodaprice > 0 ? "You still owe " + sodaprice + " cents." : "Finish...");

                    }
                }
            } while (sodaprice > 0);

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```